# Move Windows profile directory?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

I'd like to move the contents of the Windows profile directory (`C:\Users` by default) to another hard drive (`U:\`).

So I'd end up with directories like:

```
U:\Administrator\...
U:\Default\...
U:\Jon-Eric\...
U:\Public\...
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would probably be to make a link after you move it. A lot of applications search for your profile folder under `C:\users` and moving it somewhere without making an association to it will give you a headache. After moving it over to `U:\<username>` create a directory symbolic link to it:

```
MKLINK /J C:\Users\ U:
```

Comment: I believe /d is a 'light' link, you may wish to try `mklink /J C:\Users\ U:\`, which would also save a little time when you add new user accounts

Comment: Even better, added.

Comment: Warning: This seemed to work, but it [caused Volume Shadow Copy (and consequently, backups) to fail](http://superuser.com/questions/91960) until the link was removed.

Answer (score 1):

copy profiles to u:

change

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\ProfilesDirectory`

value for future profiles and corresponding ProfileImagePath values for each of your existing (and relocated) profiles.

or just add this to startup:

`subst u: "C:\Documents and Settings"` :)

links approach is good too. http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html
this tool seems best in convenience to operate with them.