# Mozy fails along with this error

Tags: windows, backup, event-log, vss, volume-shadow-copy

Any idea how to fix this?

MozyHome backup is failing at the same time with a *FilesystemError2*.

Windows 7 64-bit. Thanks!

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        VSS
Date:          12/18/2009 12:51:12 AM
Event ID:      8194
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Description:
Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error querying for the IVssWriterCallback interface.  hr = 0x80070005, Access is denied.
. This is often caused by incorrect security settings in either the writer or requestor process. 

Operation:
   Gathering Writer Data

Context:
   Writer Class Id: {35e81631-13e1-48db-97fc-d5bc721bb18a}
   Writer Name: NPS VSS Writer
   Writer Instance ID: {adcd44dc-649f-4e49-9a61-5d5040bbc5fa}

Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Error calling a routine on a Shadow Copy Provider {b5946137-7b9f-4925-af80-51abd60b20d5}. Routine details Cannot ask provider {b5946137-7b9f-4925-af80-51abd60b20d5} if volume is supported. [0x8000ffff] [hr = 0x8000ffff, Catastrophic failure
]. 

Operation:
   Check If Volume Is Supported by Provider
   Add a Volume to a Shadow Copy Set

Context:
   Execution Context: Coordinator
   Provider ID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
   Volume Name: \\?\Volume{684258d6-dd42-11de-a07e-001fd09d9b08}\
   Execution Context: Coordinator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem turned out to be this:

[I had moved my *Users* directory](https://superuser.com/questions/77214/move-windows-profile-directory) to a second drive and put a link to it in its place.

No backup programs worked until I removed the link and moved the directory back.

Answer (score -2):

Look at the [Mozy KB](http://support.mozy.com/docs/en-user-home-win/guide/tasks/filesystemerror2.html) it has a few solutions you can try.

Comment: That page doesn't address the Volume Shadow Copy error I posted. (And doesn't really offer much help.)