# Problems with Volume Shadow Copy on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vss

I am having a problem with Volume Shadow Copy on my Windows 7 Ultimate PC.
Basically, I cannot use any program that relies on Volume Shadow Copy as they always fail (including Windows Backup) with a whole list of errors (depending on the program). 
For example, when I run Windows Backup, I get:

```
The backup was not successful. The error is: Windows Backup failed while trying to read from the shadow copy on one of the volumes being backed up. Please check in the event logs for any relevant errors. (0x81000037).
```

Then I get this VSS Error:

```
Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error querying for the IVssWriterCallback interface.  hr = 0x80070005, Access is denied.
. This is often caused by incorrect security settings in either the writer or requestor process. 

Operation:
   Gathering Writer Data

Context:
   Writer Class Id: {e8132975-6f93-4464-a53e-1050253ae220}
   Writer Name: System Writer
   Writer Instance ID: {33e11ab5-bc29-4cd0-b993-656570b23fe3}
```

Then when I run Paragon System Backup (version 9.5), I get the following (after it tells me there's a problem with VSS):

```
Volume Shadow Copy Service information: The COM Server with CLSID {4e14fba2-2e22-11d1-9964-00c04fbbb345} and name CEventSystem cannot be started. [0x80070013, The media is write protected.
] 

Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error calling routine CoCreateInstance.  hr = 0x80070013, The media is write protected.
. 

Volume Shadow Copy Service information: The COM Server with CLSID {4e14fba2-2e22-11d1-9964-00c04fbbb345} and name CEventSystem cannot be started. [0x80070013, The media is write protected.
] 

Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error calling routine CoCreateInstance.  hr = 0x80070013, The media is write protected.
.
```

Then I get a Information Message saying:

```
The VSS service is shutting down due to idle timeout.
```

(I got 5 of those when I tried to run a backup yesterday)

Then I get these warnings:

```
Volume Shadow Copy Service warning: VSS was denied access to the root of volume \\?\Volume{2d3b403a-2f5a-11df-846a-005056c00008}\. Denying administrators from accessing volume roots can cause many unexpected failures, and will prevent VSS from functioning properly.  Check security on the volume, and try the operation again. 

Operation:
   Removing auto-release shadow copies
   Loading provider

Context:
   Execution Context: System Provider

Volume Shadow Copy Service warning: VSS was denied access to the root of volume \\?\Volume{2d3b403a-2f5a-11df-846a-005056c00008}\. Denying administrators from accessing volume roots can cause many unexpected failures, and will prevent VSS from functioning properly.  Check security on the volume, and try the operation again. 

Operation:
   Automatically choosing a diff-area volume
   Processing EndPrepareSnapshots

Context:
   Execution Context: System Provider

Volume Shadow Copy Service warning: VSS was denied access to the root of volume \\?\Volume{2d3b403a-2f5a-11df-846a-005056c00008}\. Denying administrators from accessing volume roots can cause many unexpected failures, and will prevent VSS from functioning properly.  Check security on the volume, and try the operation again. 

Operation:
   Automatically choosing a diff-area volume
   Processing EndPrepareSnapshots

Context:
   Execution Context: System Provider
```

When I run vssadmin list writer:

```
Writer name: 'Task Scheduler Writer'
   Writer Id: {d61d61c8-d73a-4eee-8cdd-f6f9786b7124}
   Writer Instance Id: {1bddd48e-5052-49db-9b07-b96f96727e6b}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'VSS Metadata Store Writer'
   Writer Id: {75dfb225-e2e4-4d39-9ac9-ffaff65ddf06}
   Writer Instance Id: {088e7a7d-09a8-4cc6-a60
```

Comment: Just out of interest, do you, or have you ever run BitLocker?

Comment: No, I can't activate it as I don't have Trusted Platform Module and couldn't be bothered to try any of the other methods of activating it...

Comment: Are you running as an Administrator? Have you tried running as *the* Administrator? Check Services and see if the Volume Shadow Copy service is running and set to run as the Local System account.

Comment: @Hello71: Thanks for the comment, sorry for my delay in replying I haven't had Internet until Today... I am an Administrator and I checked the Service and it was running under my User-name, so I've set it to the "Local System" Account and I'll see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace your Mounted Volume `\\?\Volume{2d3b403a-2f5a-11df-846a-005056c00008}\` by a Junction and the error should go away; Microsoft's [MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973455) says that error `0x81000037`

> "occurs if the reparse point is a **mounted volume** that contains compressed files (for example, multimedia files, .zip files, and so on)"

(emphasis mine)

Using [Hard Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) you can create "Junctions" to replace the "Mounted Volume" you are currently using. This is the HardLinkShellExt context menu I get when dragging my CD drive into a folder with the right mouse button:

[image]

- **Doesn't work:** with "mounted volume" included in Library included in Backup:

[image: with mounted volume in library, no backup possible]

- **Does work:** with "junction"  included in Library included in Backup:

[image: with junction, backup works]

See [this answer I gave](https://superuser.com/questions/298019/what-can-i-do-about-windows-7-backup-error-0x81000037-apparently-caused-by-repar/339858#339858) to a similar question (but with different cause) for more details about the topic.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be related, but...

[I had similar trouble](https://superuser.com/questions/91960/mozy-fails-along-with-this-error) when I [moved my Users directory](https://superuser.com/questions/77214/move-windows-profile-directory) to another drive and linked to it.

Only when I removed the link did everything finally start working again.

Comment: Removing the link is a solution, but you can also just change the type of link you use. See [my answer](http://superuser.com/questions/154622/problems-with-volume-shadow-copy-on-windows-7/339881#339881) to this question.